# Is OSX vulnerable / susceptible to Gameover Zeus

Tags: virus, macos

I've heard a TON of vague info on Gameover Zeus recently. One detail I can't seem to find is if it affects OSX?

- when I say I can't find it I mean from a credible source. I've found loads of people on forums saying the classic "Macs cant get viruses", but not any hard facts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Zeus family of malware does not infect OSX, [only Windows](http://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-150A). Macs can of course be infected with malware, anyone who says otherwise is sorely mistaken. Some more info, GameoverZeus is simply an improved Zeus. It is run as a P2P (peer to peer) network, and operated by an HTTP control panel. The source code of Zeus can be found with a Google search so that's how that happened. It's one of, if not the most sophisticated bots on the market next to TDL. It's even able to bypass two factor authentication, along with all of the plugins you would see in bots like SpyEye, ICE9, Carberp, and Citadel.

Comment: Always try to provide proof of claims. Add a link to your answers that provide details that back up what you've said.

Comment: Will do in the future. This is knowledge I have personally acquired, however this backs some of it up. www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-150A

Answer (score 1):

It only targets windows machines. Your only risk is if you use windows or a windows VM